# Running a Snowflake Task on the first non-weekend day of the month (using cron)

Tags: cron, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, cron-task

Right now, I only know how to set it to the first of the month (irrespective of whether it's a weekend). The sample code from the task is a follows:

```
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 2 1 * * Europe/Dublin'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to schedule a task to run on the first non-weekend day of the month.

Workaround:

1. Schedule your job to run on days 1-3 and call a stored procedure
2. Inside your SP, check if the job is already executed this month (you may use a table to persist the last run)
3. Insider your SP, check if it's a weekday, else end the SP without executing the rest of the task